# vim как перейти на новую строку

Tags: vim

Никак не могу нагуглить, как можно перейти на новую строку в vim в Insert mode, если курсор находиться посреди выражения

```
print('Example. Cursor here|')
```

Вим изучаю паралельно с python. 
Для PHP пользуюсь Netbeans, там есть хоткей Shift + Enter, очень не хватает этой возможности.

Comment: https://habr.com/post/426255/ - там есть картинка с некоторыми инструкциями для Vim'а

Comment: к сожалению, я не увидел там ответа на свой вопрос.

Comment: `escape`, затем `o`

Comment: Пока я так и делаю. Но напрягает, что постоянно надо менять режимы, даже не смотря на то, что я замапил jk kj на esc. Мне кажется, что это не правильно, хотя я пока только изучаю vim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если верно понял суть вопроса, то в *vimrc* можно задать

```
exe "set <M-o>=\eo"
nnoremap <M-o> o
inoremap <M-o> <Esc>o
```

В итоге по *Alt+o* можно переводить курсов на новую строку.

Answer (score 1):

В *Insert mode* возможны следующие комбинации для перехода на начало нижней строки:

- **Ctrl+o, Enter** - переход на начало следующей сроки
- **Ctrl+o, o** - переход на начало вновь созданной следующей сроки